# linq to sql vs ado.net - performance in terms of connection being open

Tags: linq-to-sql, ado.net

I have to get records from a table(about 40 columns),  process each record, call a web service on this record, wait for its response and update the record to database.

Now, I see 2 options.

**1. Linq to Sql**

**2. ADO.Net with Typed Dataset**

(I leave the option of DataReader for all the extra work I have to do.)

2 closes the connection soon after fetching the data, I can process data offline and submit changes later, i.e, I don't have keep connection open for so long. With 1, in-order to be able to submit changes at the end, I have to keep the connection open all the time.

Do you think 2 is the always the best way whenever changes need to submitted after a certain period of processing or am I missing something?

Comment: I know this is old, but since you are still active; I'll reiterate what was mentioned in Jim's answer below: L2S does *not* keep your connection open as you suggest. It closes as soon as it loads the objects, and re-opens when you save changes. Entity Framework likewise does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Linq to SQL or Entity Framework keep the connection open while you are working with the fetched objects. If you want to take advantage of the change tracking capabilities of the various contexts, you need to keep the context object in scope, but that doesn't mean the connection to the database remains open during that period. In actuality, the connection is only open while you are iterating on the results (databinding) and when you call SubmitChanges/SaveChanges. Otherwise the connetion is closed.

These technologies use ADO.Net DataReaders and command objects under the covers. There's still no concept of open cursors like you had back in the VB6 days.

Answer (score 1):

L2S or Entity Framework introduce a bit of overhead, but honestly the time you save is well worth it and whenever you perform a Linq query on your objects the SQL is optimized for you.

Plain old ADO.Net is old school - Linq is the way to go now.

Comment: I am not actually worried about the overhead involved in generating sql and optimization. And both L2S and ADO.Net give me data in a list of typed classes and handle the updates and inserts for me. I don't see how much of time I am saving here. what I am trying to analyze is connection being open for a length of time vs not being open? (I am not sure what exactly happens in the background when a connection is open, how much resources it is consuming, how much of a load it is on sql server.)

Comment: L2S and L2E use SQLConnection behind the scenes for you, and open and close connection each time you interact with the DataContext. You don't need to manage opening and closing your connection objects. And coding is simplified since you can use a clean Linq statement to retrieve domain objects and immediately begin using their properties - no need to create an object and populate it from a dataset and vice-versa when you go to save the data back to SQL Server.

Comment: A year ago I started programming, and I was using ADO.NET out of ignorance. Once I discovered LINQ I was very happy...

Comment: @Nick Yeah, for anyone reading this, if you haven't tried Linq just do one of the tutorials and you will be blown away at how much cleaner it is ;)

Comment: working with the sqlDataAdaptor,sqlDataReader etc was so confusing to me. I'll never go back!

Answer (score 0):

> Plain old ADO.Net is old school - Linq is the way to go now.

Microsoft caters to newbies and sells itself to the masses as a "hobbyist" language.

LINQ allows developers to query a datasource who have no business accessing a data source.

Having deep knowledge and a brain enough to write your own optimized T-SQL is perhaps is a desireable skill, not laughable as, "old school".

As a software engineer a person should move in the direction of writing software which can perform as efficient and fast as possible. The whole "saving development time" argument for choosing a higher level construct because it is all too simple to implement speaks to how crappy the program will perform if stacked up next to a senior engineers version.

Don't get sold on latest and greatest offerings that make coding "faster".  If you are smart enough to do it yourself, then do it yourself and avoid having a LINQ syntax write T-SQL for you.

There is a measure of scale in the business world where microseconds count, and being a valuable commodity to a company will put your deep knowledge to the test when your software needs to run as fast as you know how to make it.

In short, it is never out of style to have deep knowledge.

Comment: Ha ha, you just did the same thing.  You did not answer the post either.  I was going off on Winger's post.  Hence his quote about old school.  You sound like a newbie yourself.

Comment: And furthermore, if you could add 2 and 2 together I DID answer the question.  I said to write the T-SQL yourself, which... rub two sticks together and deduce that to mean ADO.